# Binding issu with label in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, binding

I am really new on xamarin. what i am trying is after login from a content page, a shell page will show. and in shell page i have a flyout, there i want to show username and mail

Google service to login with google account

```
    **private readonly IGoogleManager _googleManager = DependencyService.Get<IGoogleManager>();

    public bool IsGoogleLogedIn { get; set; }
    public ICommand GoogleLoginommand { get => new Command(GoogleLogin); }
    public ICommand GoogleLogoutCommand { get => new Command(GoogleLogout); }
    private void GoogleLogout()
    {
        if (IsGoogleLogedIn)
        {
            _googleManager.Logout();
        }
        IsGoogleLogedIn = false;
        App.Current.MainPage = new LoginView();
    }
    private void GoogleLogin()
    {
        ActivityIndicatorVisableCommand.Execute(null);
        _googleManager.Login(OnGoogleLoginComplete);
    }
    private void OnGoogleLoginComplete(GoogleUser googleUser, string message)
    {
        
        if (googleUser != null)
        {
            
            UserFullName = googleUser.Name;
            UserEmail = googleUser.Email;
            var imgProfile = googleUser.Picture;
            IsGoogleLogedIn = true;
            App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message", message, "Ok");
            ActivityIndicatorVisableCommand.Execute(null);
            return;
        }
        
    }**
```

Trying to add username in shellpage

```
 **private string _UserFullName = string.Empty;
    public string UserFullName
    {
        set
        {
            if (_UserFullName != value) { _UserFullName = value; }
            OnUserFullNamePropertyChanged("UserFullName");
        }
        get
        {
            return _UserFullName;
        }
    }
    void OnUserFullNamePropertyChanged(string _UserFullName_)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(_UserFullName_)));
    }
    //After login should show username and email on flyout header---------------- End**
```

here is my xmal code for binding

```
        **<Grid Grid.Column="1"  WidthRequest="180">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding UserFullName}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding UserEmail}" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
    </Grid>**
```

Comment: it is impossible to tell how these different pieces of code relate to each other.  Is the `UserFullName` in the services code the same as shown in the 2nd block?  Is the 2nd block a code-behind or a VM class?  What is the BindingContext for the page?  Finally, sprinkling "**" throughout your code just makes it harder to read, please do not do that.

Comment: sorry stackoverflow did not let me to post without  sprinkling . I have uploaded in github : https://github.com/younusrahman/SRConnectingNew

Comment: https://github.com/younusrahman/SRConnectingNew

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Linking to code in an offsite repo is not a substitute for including the relevant portions of your code in your post

Comment: but, I'll point out that the ShellHeader and the LoginPage each have their **own separate instance** of `LoginViewModel` so changes made to one instance will not effect the other instance

Comment: still trying to understand. what i am actully missing

Comment: But when i try private string _UserFullName = "test";  then it works why??

Comment: because you are hardcoding the value.  When you set the UserFullName in the LoginPage, it is modify it's instance of LoginViewModel, which has NO impact on the separate instance of LoginViewModel used by ShellHeader